# Vue Material Kit PRO Select active tab

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using the Vue Material Kit PRO template and I'm trying to dynamically change the active tab in a JavaScript function

I have

```
             <tabs
                pills-align="center"
                :tab-active= 1
                :tab-name="['Monthly', 'Yearly']"
                plain
                color-button="success"
              >
                <!-- here you can add your content for tab-content -->
                <template slot="tab-pane-1" />
                <template slot="tab-pane-2" />
              </tabs>
```

And I see where

```
        tab-active = 1
```

and if I set it to

```
       tab-active = 2
```

then the page will display with tab 2 active.

However, I tried to set

```
    :tab-active =  activeTab
```

and have in script

```
          activeTab: 1
```

and that works fine.

But if I try to change it to

```
      this.activeTab = 2
```

nothing happens.  Can someone point me in the right dirrection?

Comment: I get you're in a delicate position, since you paid for a service you're not getting. But, in order to help you one would need to pay for the same s*\*\*y service just to be able to replicate your issue and provide you with the answer you paid for... but for free. Would ***you*** do that? Realistically, the least you should provide is a [mcve]. Without one, I don't see how anyone (without a Creative Tim subscription) could help.

Comment: I totally agree- I just added the line paid subscription to let others now that buying their templates and paying the additional cost for support does not work really help.  It was more of an act of frustration.  I've owned various templates from them over the years and never needed support.  Now that I do- no contact-- Maybe it's the virus-- I don't know and I hope not.

Comment: I totally understand. If you're able to setup a working example, I'm willing to take a look. Use `codesanbox.io` if you need a multi-file based node environment.